# Spark Streaming (Spark 1.6) vs Structured Streaming (Spark 2.2)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In Spark 2.2, I was using Spark Streaming with Kafka as follows:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
              .setAppName("Test")
              .setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "metadata.broker.list" -> "host1:port1,host2:port2",
      "group.id" -> "group",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "largest")
    val dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet).map(_._2)

dstream.foreachRDD(rdd => { ...
})

ssc.start()

ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Now I need to do the same using Spark 2.2. I was reading about Structured Streaming. Do I understand correctly that I should create a streaming DataFrame, without the need to use `ssc.start()` and `ssc.awaitTermination()`?

Will this be a complete correct substitution of the code shown above?

```
val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("Test")
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .getOrCreate()

val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
      .option("subscribe", "topic1")
      .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]
```

Where do I define `"group.id" -> group` and `"auto.offset.reset" -> "largest"`?

**UPDATE:**

I also found a bit different approach:

```
val rawData: DataFrame = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", metadataBrokerList)
      .option("subscribe", inputKafkaTopic)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "true")
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]
```

Can I then use `rawData` as `rawData.foreachRDD(rdd => { ... })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't. You still need a query (sink). In its simplest form

```
val keyValueDf = df
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]

val query = keyValueDf
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start()
```

And `awaiTermination` (or equivalent somewhere else like `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination`)

```
query.awaitTermination()
```

See [Starting Streaming Queries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#starting-streaming-queries) and [Managing Streaming Queries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#managing-streaming-queries).

To execute aribtrary code in the sink (like `foreachRDD`) you can try `writeStream.foreach` and define [`ForeachWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter):

```
val writer: ForeachWriter[Row]
df.writeStream.foreach(writer).start()
```

For options please see [Kafka Specific Configurations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations).

- `group.id` is unique for query:

  > **group.id**: Kafka source will create a unique group id for each query automatically.
- `startingOffsets` should be used in place of `auto.offset.reset`:

  > **auto.offset.reset**: Set the source option startingOffsets to specify where to start instead. Structured Streaming manages which offsets are consumed internally, rather than rely on the kafka Consumer to do it. This will ensure that no data is missed when new topics/partitions are dynamically subscribed. Note that startingOffsets only applies when a new streaming query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off.

Comment: @Markus This code examples might help you as well : https://github.com/polomarcus/Spark-Structured-Streaming-Examples/tree/master/src/main/scala/kafka